# a:link doesn't work in firefox

Tags: css, firefox

I've got problem with link styling - 
hover and active works, but link doesn't, what am i doing wrong?
How can i fix this problem?

```
    #nav{padding: 5px 230px 10px 230px;}

#nav li{
    display: inline-block;
    list-style: none;
    margin: 5px;
    padding: 1px;
    font: 20px Century Gothic;      
}

    a.navlink:link{
        color:#06AD00;
        background: white;
        border-top: 1px #958A7E solid;  
        border-bottom: 1px #958A7E solid;
        cursor:pointer;
    }
    a.navlink:visited{}
    a.navlink:hover {
        color: black; 
        background: white; 
        border-top: 1px black solid;    
        border-bottom: 1px black solid; 
        cursor:pointer;
    }
    a.navlink:active {
        color: red; 
        background: white;
        border:0;
        cursor:pointer;
    }
```

Comment: can you show your html?

Comment: Are you sure your browser thinks the link is *unvisited*?  Try clearing your history.

Comment: Note that `a.navlink:visited{}` doesn't mean *"no styling"*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've had this same problem with certain versions of Opera and older IE. I've always avoided the `:link` pseudo-class in favor of just a natural `a` style - never quite understood the reason why, but `:link` was always 50/50 while natural `a` has never failed.

Try this instead for your `:link` style:

```
a.navlink{
    ...
}
```

This will only create a default state for your `a.navlink` elements - the other pseudo-classes will still modify it properly. If it doesn't fix things for you, then my next guess would be you've got a conflicting style somewhere. Hard to know for sure without getting our hands on the rest of the source.

Comment: Yes, thank you! a.navlink{} works! a:navlink:link{} didn't, that was the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You CSS works great on my FireFox.
Make sure you define the HTML tags and attributes properly according to your CSS.

Also, note that you may see the wrong style because your links are already visited. Try to put some URLs that you didn't visit. (ex: sdfdsfdsfsfdhgsdf.com ect...)

Comment: The problem is in :link (there is no styling), not :visited (i want visited same as unisited). First I omitted :visited, so i thought puting it will solve problem, but it doesn't matter actually.

Answer (score 0):

`:link` only matches unvisited links, per spec.  If you want to match all links, you have to do something like `a.navlink:link, a.navlink:visited {}`